# How do I Set a Key and a Value in a JFace ComboViewer?

Tags: java, swt, derby, jface

I am trying to set up a combo box that will display a UserName, but when selected will send a an ID instead.

I have already set up a method that queries my Derby database and returns a multidimensional array with the UserNames and IDs.

I did some research on how to set this up and found several posts suggesting JFace, but nothing on how to accomplish this.

I have tried setData(String Key, Object Value), and add(String String, int index).
I have also looked at DataBinding, but haven't found anything that I am able to make work.

Thanks,

Update----------------------
I got it working to a point.
I think I have the content provider set up properly however when I go to run the app it prints all the labels the same as the last item in the list.

Model Provider:

```
public enum ModelProvider {
INSTANCE;

public List<Animal> Animals;
public String conn = "L:\\Dropbox\\Herd_Management\\database";
private ModelProvider() {
    Animals = new ArrayList<Animal>();
    String strSQL = null;
    strSQL = "SELECT Herd_ID FROM dbherd_management.TBLHERD";
    String[] straHerd_IDs = CC_Derby.getResultArray(conn, "", "", strSQL);
    for (int r = 0; r < straHerd_IDs.length; r++) {
        Animals.add(new Animal(Integer.parseInt(straHerd_IDs[r])));
    }
}

public List<Animal> getAnimals() {
    return Animals;
}

}
```

Snippet For Content and Label Providers:

```
            comboViewer_9 = new ComboViewer(shlHerdManagement, SWT.NONE);
            final Combo cboAnimalTag = comboViewer_9.getCombo();
            cboAnimalTag.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL,
                    true, false, 1, 1));
            cboAnimalTag.setText("<Select Animal Tag>");

            comboViewer_9.setContentProvider(new ArrayContentProvider());
                comboViewer_9.setInput(ModelProvider.INSTANCE.getAnimals());
            comboViewer_9.setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider() {
                  @Override
                  public String getText(Object element) {
                      Animal a = (Animal) element;
                      return (a.getTag());
                  }
                });
```

Animal Constructor

```
public Animal(int intAnimal_ID) {
    Connection conn = CC_Derby.createConnection("L:\\Dropbox\\Herd_Management\\database","","");
    String strSQL = "SELECT * FROM dbherd_management.TBLHERD WHERE HERD_ID ="
            + intAnimal_ID;

    try {
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet results = null;
        results = stmt.executeQuery(strSQL);
        while (results.next()) {
            intHerd_id = results.getInt(1);
            strHerd_Tag_Letter = results.getString(2);
            intHerd_Tag_Num = results.getInt(3);
            strHerd_Tag_Color = results.getString(4);
            strHerd_Sex = results.getString(5);
            strHerd_Type = results.getString(6);
            dtHerd_Birthdate = results.getString(7);
            intHerd_Sire = results.getInt(8);
            intHerd_Dam = results.getInt(9);
            intHerd_Owner = results.getInt(10);
            strHerd_TimeStamp = results.getString(11);
            strHerd_Status = results.getString(12);
            dtHerd_Status_Date = results.getString(13);
        }
        results.close();
        stmt.close();
        CC_Derby.shutdown(stmt, conn);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

getTag Method

```
public String getTag(){
    String strResult = null;
    String l = null;
    int n = 0;
    String c = null;
    l = getHerd_Tag_Letter();
    n = getHerd_Tag_Num();
    c = getHerd_Tag_Color();
    if(l == null){
        l ="";
    }
    if(c == null){
        c = "";
    }
    strResult = l + n + " " + c;
    return strResult;
}
```

Comment: Viewer setup looks OK. It's not clear from the code what is the value of `getTag()`.

Comment: I added the Animal Constructor and getTag() Method

Comment: I don't see any problems here, sorry. I can only suggest debugging...

Comment: Ok one more question.
How do I  go about getting the key value stored in the combo?
I'm hoping if I can get the key values it will help me see what is going on with the labels.

Comment: Add `ISelectionChangedListener` to the viewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a viewer with a [content provider](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/IContentProvider.html) and a [label provider](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ILabelProvider.html). Content provider serves the objects (UserNameIdPair), label provider provides labels (UserName string). View's [selection listeners](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/viewers/ISelectionChangedListener.html) will be "sent" objects provided by content provider.

Comment: Edit Question with new findings.